# Vertical aligment with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with vertical alignment in a `tabular` environment with `tikzpicture`.

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture} 
& = & 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
& * & 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives a result:
[image]

But what I want is more like this:
[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `baseline` option to your `tikzpicture`s. (Use `$\ast$` instead of plain `*`, to adjust the baseline)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,1.4-1.4/2)}]
        \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,1.6);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    & = & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,1.4-1.4/2)}]
        \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,1.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    & $\ast$ & 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,2.8-1.4/2)}]
        \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is to set the `baseline` key of the environment

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture} 
& = & 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
& * & 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=0.7cm]current bounding box.center)}]% We know the step
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The other one is drawing all by TikZ,

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,1.6);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0.8,0)}]
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,1.6);  
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(4.4,-1.4)}]
  \draw[step=0.2cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (0.2,3);  
\end{scope}
\node at (0.5,0.8) {$=$};
\node at (4.1,0.8) {${\times}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]